# StackOverflowException at startup when adding ApplicationInsightsTelemetryProcessor to DI (ASP.NET Core 2.2)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, azure-application-insights

I just updated a ASP.NET Core Web API from Core 2.1 to Core 2.2. After the update the API refuses to start, throwing a StackOverflowException. 
I luckily found out that the source of the exception is this line inside ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryProcessor<FilteredTelemetryProcessor>();
```

Here is the implementation of the FilteredTelemetryProcessor:

```cs
public FilteredTelemetryProcessor(
            ITelemetryProcessor next,
            ILogger<FilteredTelemetryProcessor> logger,
            IHttpContextAccessor 
{
    this.Next = next;
    this.logger = logger;
    this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
}

     public void Process(ITelemetry item)
     {
            if (!this.OKtoSend(item))
            {
                // Returning breakes the chain, thus not sending the item
                return;
            }

            this.Next.Process(item);
        }

        private bool OKtoSend(ITelemetry item)
        {
            if (item is RequestTelemetry request)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(request.Url);
                if (request.Url.LocalPath == "/" ||
                    request.Url.LocalPath == "/favicon.ico")
                {
                   return false;
                }

               if (request.ResponseCode == "404")
               {
                   var routeData = this.httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.GetRouteData();

                    if (routeData == null)
                    {
                        this.logger.LogWarning($"HTTP 404: Es wurde versucht einen Api Endpunkt aufzurufen der nicht existiert: {request.Url.LocalPath}");
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.logger.LogWarning($"Für Aktion mit URL: {request.Url.LocalPath} wurde HTTP 404 geworfen!");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
```

Why is this not working with Core 2.2 but with 2.1 it works?

Comment: Please paste your startup,cs file too also meanwhile take a look at https://github.com/seesharper/LightInject/issues/462

Comment: Here is the startup:  https://gist.github.com/zuckerthoben/b7d5ddf2d1a75ea134bf73c932554fc9
@MohitVerma

Comment: If Application Insights is also subscribed to ILogger output in .NET Core 2.2 case, then ILogger statements within the processor will produce another telemetry item. Initializers and Processors are executed on that item synchronously, so this processor will be called inside itself infinitely leading to StackOverflow. To workaround - avoid creation of telemetry items within telemetry pipeline extensibility points such as within Processors.

Comment: Known issue in AppInsights SDK: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/1536

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and managed to find a workaround by removing (and not using) `ILogger<FilteredTelemetryProcessor>` that is passed to the constructor. I couldn't find the exact reason causing the issue, but seems like the problem has something to do with circular dependencies resulting in `StackOverflowException`.